# Django: relative url not working with post calls in ajax

Tags: ajax, django, django-urls, django-csrf

I am trying to use relative url with a post ajax call as follows:

Current url path:

```
http://localhost:8000/customer/0/location/0/user/0/
```

I need to change to different directoy.

```
var absolute = "http://localhost:8000/customer/0/location/0/line_group/addLine/2/";//+phone_id;
var relative= "../../line_group/addLine/1"

            $.get(relative,function(data){
            //this works     
            alert(data);
            });

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: relative,
            data: "test=test1",
            error:function(data){
            //throws error when using relative path  
            alert('error');
            },
            success:function(data){
            // works fine when using absolute path 
            alert('success');
            }
            });
            //same thing using just post        
            $.post(relative,test,function(data){
            //Error on relative path
            alert(data);
            return false;
            });
```

For my get calls both, absolute and relative url, return data.

But for POST call, when I use relative url, I get internal server error.(absolute URL works fine)
I do not think it has got to do with CSRF, as in my view I have also include @csrf_exempt for test purposes. 
(I have included https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax in request)

The chrome debugger gives me the following error message on the post call with relative URL.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) http://localhost:8000/customer/0/location/0/line_group/addLine/1
```

However as you can see it does provide me the complete url link, which I want to access.
And when I click directly on the link, I get the data of the page.

The view is really simple:

```
@csrf_exempt
def addNewLine(request, customer_id, location_id, phone_id,**kwargs):
      error_msg = u"No POST data sent."            
      context = {}
      return render_to_response('line_group/mytest.html', context)
```

Any body has any suggestion, as to why the relative url path fails on POST call?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome Network section you can preview the error explanation if you have `DEBUG=True`.

As you have no slash at the end of `var relative= "../../line_group/addLine/1"`, it might be that CommonMiddleware redirects your request. Set `APPEND_SLASH = False` in project settings if you want to keep your URL as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The missing / was causing the error.
But I am curious why the Get request was working fine??

Comment: POST variables can't be redirected to another page.